# Release notes from git log using bash awk

Tags: git, bash, awk

We follow a commit message policy that allows us to parse git log for release notes.

#### [category US123] Description of what is changed

eg:

- [feature US123] Added the version number to the meta:version tag of every page. Better for support.
- [dev US123] remove development entries before production
- [settings US123] New STS webservice url for UAT

The bash script below parses the log, but there's a trailing number after each user story / defect.

Is this a side effect of awk? What needs to change to remove the trailing number?

`git log -100 --pretty="%s" | grep -io "\(DE\|US\)[0-9]\{3,\}" | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1; print system("git log --pretty=\"%cI %an %s\" | grep -i -v \"Merge\" | grep -i "$1)}'`

[image]

Comment: that is probably because of `system` function you called inside `awk`. This could be done in some other way if you provide sample input text and desired output data.

Comment: Could you provide us some example of commit messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `print system(...)` with just `system(...)`:

```
git log -100 --pretty="%s" | grep -io "\(DE\|US\)[0-9]\{3,\}" | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1; system("git log --pretty=\"%cI %an %s\" | grep -i -v \"Merge\" | grep -i "$1)}'
```

`system()` function prints to stdout by itself, when you call `print system(...)` you actually print exit code returned by `system()`.

Comment: Thanks! That nailed it.